# Override SSH message when accessed via HTTP

Tags: ssh, http

If you access my server via HTTP using the SSH port (22), you'll see a message like this:

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1

Could be possible to display a different message?

Comment: Downvoter, it would be great if you could tell me why. Thanks :)

Comment: You could look around at the file called `\etc\motd` I've seen that file in many different distributions of Linux. I believe it's also available for Debian. (i use CentOS) Here is a link : [protect-ssh-logins-with-ssh-motd-banner-messages/](http://www.tecmint.com/protect-ssh-logins-with-ssh-motd-banner-messages/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Debian/Ubuntu version identification is [a Debian-ism](https://lists.debian.org/debian-ssh/2010/01/msg00094.html) which isn't present in standard OpenSSH.

You can disable it by setting `DebianBanner no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

The end result will be:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1
```

You should not disable this as [it's required to negotiate the SSH protocol connection](http://www.openssh.com/faq.html#2.14).

Comment: Small amendment: you can in fact remove or change anything after "SSH-2.0-". Those are required by the SSH protocol; the rest of the string is a comment, not interpreted by the protocol. Note that if you do that, however, you may cause trouble for clients which identify server implementations in this way and turn on specific features or workarounds for known incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Banner option in */etc/ssh/sshd_config*:

`The contents of the specified file are sent to the remote user before authentication is allowed. If the argument is “none” then no banner is displayed. This option is only available for protocol version 2. By default, no banner is displayed.`

This way you cannot remove the version string, but is very handy to use it to provide legal information.